# E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have installed docker on windows 10 pro. I am facing an issue while running the following command in git-bash.

docker-compose up -d --build

and got following error.

```
E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation
(23) Failed writing body
Error executing command, exiting
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Please consider marking this question as answered.

Answer (score 359, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, run this first:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2
```

or

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg
```

Comment: gnupg is sufficient. gnupg2 is a dummy transitional package

Comment: but what if I get: `#0 0.207 E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation` even after your advice?

Comment: ```E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Comment: Actually I can not run `apt-get update`:
`W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY 605C66F00D6C9793`
I tried to add key:
`apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0E98404D386FA1D9
E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation`
Yeah, I can not install `gnupg`, because I can not run `apt update` which requires `gnupg`. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 62):

I faced the same issue:

> E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation

I resolved by using the following commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install gnupg
```

Comment: Just a note for someone new to docker, add this to your docker file, don't install gnupg on host pc

Comment: This works well for Bitnami's Ubuntu 18.04 instances as well. +1

Comment: But I can not install `gnupg`, because I can not run `apt update` which requires `gnupg`. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 48):

In addition to existing answers:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg
```

-y flag agrees to terms during installation process. It is important not to break the build

Comment: +1 for following [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#apt-get) :: _Always combine RUN apt-get update with apt-get install in the same RUN statement._

Comment: ...then also `&& apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*`

Comment: This works only if you can run `apt-get update` but what if signatures were expired and there is no `gnupg` installed?

Answer (score 7):

Just install the updated versions of all of them.

`apt-get install -y gnupg2 gnupg gnupg1`

Comment: gnupg is sufficient, gnupg1 is the "classic" version and gnugp2 refers to gnugp for recent distros

Comment: @rmuller very important comment, thanks for adding that

Answer (score 4):

I have debian 9 and to fix this i used the new library as follows:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gpgv /usr/bin/gnupg2
```